# Matching a large set of words against a list of small sets

Tags: algorithm, set, nlp

I feel like there could be an algorithm for this but I just don't know what it'd be called.

Let's say you have a 'large' set of words, 
`('apple', 'orange', 'potato', 'tomato', 'river', 'mountain', 'forest')`

and a list of smaller sets that will be considered requirements:
`[('apple'), 
('potato', 'tomato'), 
('cockroach', 'dynamite')]`

Is there a way to hash/precompute the list of smaller sets such that you can tell which sets of required words are fulfilled without having to go through them one-by-one?
In this example, the function would tell you the first two requirements were met ('apple') and ('potato','tomato').

Comment: You might be able to use a Bloom filter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to make a fast "yes - maybe" or "no" comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any preprocessing on the requirement side will help.

On the larger set side, however, you can presort that list which allows you to do a **binary search** when checking constraints.

If you have `n` elements in the large set, and `k` elements in a requirement, it will take you `O(kn)` time to search naively by scanning the entire large set.  Using a binary search however will take you `O(klog(n))` time.  The difference between the two is enormous in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the large list and all of the small lists. This means that you can match the smaller lists by iterating through the large list, and checking the first unmatched element of each of the smaller lists, because the strings in the smaller list will be matched in order.

To do this efficiently create a hashset to check if strings exist in the large set, and a hash that maps from a string key to a set of all the string lists where that string is the first unmatched element. Your algorithm in pseudo code is:

```
for each string S in large list:
    set of lists SOL = hashmap[S]
    for each list L in SOL:
        remove L from SOL and remove SOL from hashmap if now empty
        find next string S2 in L after S
        if S2 doesn't exist (i.e. S was the last unmatched string in the small list)
            L is a match, add to your list of matches
        else if S2 is in largelisthashset
            set of lists SOL2 = hashmap[S2], create if doesn't exist
            add L to SOL2
            hashmap[S2] = SOL2
```

You can maintain a pointer to the current position in each small list so the "find next string S2 in L after S" step is O(1). So you'd have an object with a string list and an index, and you'd then have a set of these objects stored in the hash for each string. The sets don't need to be sorted.

Should be O(n log(n)) for the initial sort and O(n * m) to find the matching string lists, assuming hash lookups are O(1), with m being the average number of smallers lists containing each string in the larger list (in practise less because a string in a smaller list will only be matched if all the previous strings in the list were matched).

This algorithm saves time compared to the check-each-list approach because smaller lists that don't contain items in the larger list are never processed. If the large list is much larger and there are only a small number of smaller lists then it's slower, because checking each smaller list using a hash of items in the large list you can avoid processing items in the large list that aren't in any of the smaller lists. However you could speed it up by maintaining a sorted list of strings that have set of lists in your hashmap, and using the large list hashset (or a hash of strings to indices in the large list) to skip over strings in the large list in your outer loop that don't have any entries in the hashmap.

So it really depends on the relative lengths, overlap and number of your lists.